# Error while executing Simple Spring Boot Application in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I have recently installed Spring Tool Suite 4.0.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 and tried to run hello world spring application but it gives the following compile-time error. I have searched on google a lot but cannot find the relevant info.
Error:

"Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
Archive for required library: '/home/anshul/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-test/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar' in project 'demo' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file"

Comment: Try to downgrade the version of the parrent : spring-boot-starter-parent, i think you use 2.1.0.RELEASE ? try to change it by 2.0.0.RELEASE and tel me

Comment: what is your gradle or maven version and jdk?

Comment: @TinyOS Yeah, it worked! But can you please give a detailed explanation of why I was wrong. Also, it is now giving a cryptic warning: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1

Comment: @Deadpool <java.version>1.8</java.version>  & <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the JAR file in your local Maven repository is corrupted. The easiest way to solve this is to completely wipe out the local Maven repo (delete everything under `.m2/repository` and kick off an `Update Maven Project...` in STS. That will trigger Maven to download the dependencies again.

Comment: But how can JAR file be corrupted. I just followed the simple steps: Download the tar.gz file from spring.io and then just extract it.

Comment: We all wonder about this. It is just a fact of life that files in the local maven repository may get corrupted from time to time. Maybe its because an error that happened during download, or some bug in maven or eclipse m2e maven tooling. Or... who knows. Frustrating, I know. Fortunately, the problem is usually easily remedied by deleting the local repo (or even more selectively, just delete only the 'bad' artefact.